# Dispatching on the host header asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I'd like to implement Dispatching on the host header like [stackexchange team](http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/post/459188139/speeding-up-stackexchange)  did. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is simply taking in HttpContext.Current.Request.Url  or another request value and dynamically setting a connection string.

So a user requests horsesaresweet.com and connects to the horsesaresweet database.

*Nothing fancy.*